# clickhouse copier to keep two tables on different clusters in sync forever

Tags: clickhouse

We have a use case to copy our data onto a clients CH cluster. We need to include historical data and  incremental data(every 5 -6 mins).
Can we use Clickhouse-copier/clickhouse-backup for this?(keep the copy running forever)

The number of records every 5mins will be in the range of 200-500. We want to avoid doing the select ... insert as it will require more dev effort and another external process to monitor.

From what I have seen it looks like Clickhouse-copier is a one time copy operation tool?
is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure that using [clickhouse-copier](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/operations/utilities/clickhouse-copier/) is the right way because it isn't designed to replicate data but once time copier.

You, of course, can create a batch-file that will call *clickhouse-copier* repeatedly, and before each call modify the *<where_condition>* in its config-file.

The same way can be used *clickhouse-client*.

Both ones look pretty awkward.

---

I would rely on [CH replication](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/engines/table-engines/mergetree-family/replication/) to delegate CH to do data copying. It requires to create two tables with the same schema and *zoo_path*, and share the same Zookeper:

```sql
/* source-cluster table */
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS source_db.source_table
(
  ..
)
ENGINE = ReplicatedMergeTree('/clickhouse/replicated/tables/source_db/source_table', 'replica_1')
ORDER BY ..;

/* destination-cluster table */
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS destination_db.destination_table
(
  ..
)
ENGINE = ReplicatedMergeTree('/clickhouse/replicated/tables/source_db/source_table', 'replica_2')
ORDER BY ..;
```